# Cannot unnest json in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

```
create table json_example as
select '[{"a":1,"b":"foo"},{"a":"2","c":"bar"}]'::jsonb as value

select * from json_example
```

the following is working fine:

```
select * from json_array_elements('[{"a":1,"b":"foo"},{"a":"2","c":"bar"}]')
```

And i want to do the same, only difference that json is coming from a table. how to do the same using json_example table value field?

Comment: update: i have jsonb data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cross join` *json_array_elements* with the table

```
select j.* from json_example cross join
json_array_elements(value) as j
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=249ee7ede8afd72abb4e13f556535b5e)

Comment: Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: failed to find conversion function from unknown to json

Comment: @clairvoyant : As I've shown in the demo, you should cast the column to json if you're using a `ctas` . It'll be created as unknown by default even if you've used a valid `json`

Comment: yes like that its work, porblem is that i have an existing table where values is a jsonb. is there something similar solution for that?

Comment: @clairvoyant : You should have told that. In that case you may use `jsonb_array_elements`

Comment: select j.* from json_example  cross join
jsonb_array_elements(value) as j . still gives me error: Reason:
SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object

Comment: @clairvoyant : That error  doesn't look like a Postgres error. See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e040885ce68daa090e7b7ddc11b362f6) it works fine for me. I don't see why it should give you that error.

Comment: @clairvoyant : You're welcome. It'd be great if you also tell us why it wasn't working earlier. It would definitely help a future answer seeker facing same kind of error.

Comment: good question, must be some silly error no worries on that. simply copy paste it again and it worked.

Comment: is there a solution where it is a left join? i am querying into a nested json and when the nested json field contains: [] then it returns no rows

Comment: is my field: value->'fields'->'subtasks'    and when it contains [] it returns no rows so thats why i need something left join

Comment: @clairvoyant : A kind suggestion - do not use comment section of an answer for further requirements / details. They should  be posted as a **separate question** with specific details.

Comment: you are right. i have opened a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551953/jsonb-array-elements-does-not-return-row-when-not-found