# jsonb_array_elements does not return row, when not found

Tags: json, postgresql

I use cross join to unnest nested json values, but when filed not found it returns no record. is there a solution for the below using left join somehow?

```
create table json_example as
select '{"id": "21397",  "fields": { "labels": [] , "subtasks": [{"id": "10217"}] }}'::jsonb as value
union all
select '{"id": "21397",  "fields": { "labels": [] ,  "subtasks" : []  }}'::jsonb
```

returns both rows:

```
select * from json_example
```

the below returns only one row:

```
select subtasks.value->>'id'  
  from json_example h cross join
       jsonb_array_elements(value->'fields'->'subtasks') as subtasks
```

how i can solve the above, problem to have both records?

Comment: May be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514968/939860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add `on true` for `left join` to work.

```
select subtasks->>'id'  
  from json_example h left join
       jsonb_array_elements(value->'fields'->'subtasks') as subtasks on true
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a cross join, a simple lateral query will do - you don't even need the `LATERAL` keyword when calling a table function:

```
select subtasks.value->>'id'  
  from json_example,
       jsonb_array_elements(value->'fields'->'subtasks') as subtasks
```

But you can also put it right inside your select expression:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(value->'fields'->'subtasks') ->> 'id'  
  from json_example
```